# How to arbitrarily manipulate line paths in circuitikz diagrams?

Tags: diagrams, line-spacing, circuitikz, logic, line

I'd like to draw this with LaTeX:

[image]

---

This is what I have so far:

[image]

```
%%%%%PREAMBLE%%%%%
\documentclass[border=0.25cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

%%%%%HEAD%%%%%
\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}

        %%%%%OBJECTS%%%%%
        \draw (-3.50,-3.00) -- ++(0,3.50) node[above] (x) {\(x\)};
        \draw (-2.50,-3.00) -- ++(0,3.50) node[above] (y) {\(y\)};
        \draw (-1.50,-3.00) -- ++(0,3.50) node[above] (z) {\(z\)};
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        \draw (+0.67,-1.00) node[and port] (and2){};
        \draw (+4.50,-1.00) node[and port] (and1){};
        \draw (+0.00,-2.50) node[not port] (not2){};
        \draw (+2.50,-1.75) node[or port]  (orr1){};

        %%%%%INPUTS%%%%%%
        \draw[fill] (and1.in 1) -- (x |- and1.in 1) circle (1pt);
        \draw[fill] (and2.in 2) -- (y |- and2.in 2) circle (1pt);
        \draw[fill] (not2.in)   -- (y |- not2.in)   circle (1pt);
        \draw[fill] (and2.in 1) -- (z |- and2.in 1) circle (1pt);
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        \draw       (and2.out)  -- (orr1.in 1);
        \draw       (not2.out)  -- (orr1.in 2);
        \draw       (orr1.out)  -- (and1.in 2);

        %%%%%OUTPUT%%%%%%
        \draw (and1.out) node[right=0.63cm](M){$M$};
        \draw (and1.out) -- (M);

%%%%%TAIL%%%%%
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

---

Obviously, I could just shift an AND gate, so they aren't directly parallel, but absolute control over the output would be preferable.

Also, it would be nice if I could get the AND and NOT gates to line up perfectly, but that's not critical.

Comment: You really ask for that output: `|-` means "use the horizontal position of the first coordinate and the vertical position of the second". Just specify an absolute coordinate instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can draw the lines as you like. The coordinates like `and1.in 1` are just `tikz` coordinates on the nodes. By adding `\usetikzlibrary{calc}` to the preamble you can do coordinate manipulations. Sometimes it is easier to see what you are doing by adding coordinates. Below `tmp` is just `and1.in 1` lifted 0.6cm. Then I draw first to the coordinate where `tmp` and `orr1.out` meet, and then back to `x`.

```
\coordinate (tmp) at ($(and1.in 1)+(0,0.6)$);
% \draw (tmp) circle (2pt);% Just to see where the coordinate is
\draw (and1.in 1) --(orr1.out |- tmp) -- (x |- tmp);
\draw[fill] (x |- tmp) circle (1pt);
```

It can also be done in one `\draw`

```
\draw (and1.in 1) -- ($(orr1.out |- and1.in 1) + (0,0.6)$) -- ($(x |- and1.in 1) + (0,0.6)$) node[fill,circle,inner sep=1pt]{};
```

[image]

I guess it was not the coloring you asked for, but here it is:-)

```
\draw[color=red!40!yellow!100,thick] (and1.in 1) -- ($(orr1.out |- and1.in 1) + (0,0.6)$) -- ($(x |- and1.in 1) + (0,0.6)$) node[fill,circle,inner sep=1pt]{};
```

[image]